# Chrome open other URL in new tab

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is it possible to open a link into a new tab, but only when the link redirects to another domain ?

"Ctrl + Click" or "RightClick --> Open in new Tab" are no solutions. I know about this, but I search an even easier way.

Example:

superuser.com --> https://superuser.com/users/218982/solaflex --> Open in same tab

superuser.com --> https://stackoverflow.com/users/2018064/solaflex --> Open in new tab

I also take extensions :)

Comment: And you do not want to right click to open them in new Tab, right?

Comment: No, not really. Ctrl + Click is also very annoying.
I hoped, that there is an extension or something else.

Comment: I understand you want this done automatically, based on the domain, but since you mention the two ways you open new tabs, I thought you might want to know that "middle click" is a great shortcut to open in a new tab (also to close tabs, if you middle click the tab itself)

Answer (score 1):

I made a Chrome extension that causes links to external ("new") domains to open in a new tab:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-domain-in-new-tab/nokdeeoiaiicgnonknihiccadnnmpeoh

The readme can be found below, or at the source Github page [here](https://github.com/ddodson5/new-domain-in-new-tab).

### Features

- Default Setup

  Will open links to new domains in a new tab for all sites after installation.
- Quick enable/disable

  Find options to enable/disable the extension for the current domain by right-clicking the extension's icon in the browser bar.
- Whitelist

  Only enable the extension on the specified sites.
- Blacklist

  Enable the extension for all *except* the specified sites.
- Visual indicator

  The extension icon will turn blue when the extension is enabled for the current domain, and red when it is disabled.

### Usage Examples

#### Whitelist

To only open search results in new tabs within Google searches:

1. Go to the options page.
2. Check "Exclude all domains by default".
3. Add "www.google.com" to the "Domains to be included" list.
4. Hit "save".

   Alternately, instead of following 3 and 4 you could:
5. Navigate to "www.google.com".
6. Right click the "New Domain in New Tab" browser icon and select "enable for current domain".

#### Blacklist

To open off-domain links in new tabs for all domains except "www.example.com":

1. Go to the options page.
2. Check "Include all domains by default". ( this is the default setting after installation )
3. Add "www.example.com" to the "Domains to be excluded" list.
4. Hit "save".

   Alternately, instead of following 3 and 4 you could:
5. Navigate to "www.example.com".
6. Right click the "New Domain in New Tab" browser icon and select "disable for current domain".

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Do you have a suggestion as to how to accomplish that? Not being snarky, I just genuinely don't know how to frame my answer besides a direct link.

Comment: You could elaborate on how to use your extension and why it solves the asker's problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac keyboard

Press ⌘-Shift and click a link,

Opens the link in a new tab and switch to that tab.

Press Shift and click a link

Opens the link in a new window.

Comment: As I said in the comments, I look for a extension, which detects it automatically and open the new tab itself when I click on it.

Comment: I missed that, sorry. I would be helpful to have that in your original question and not in the comments.

Comment: Ok, I updated it